# Is anyone having problems installing VS Tools for Apache Cordova Update 4?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I just saw VS TACO Update 4 as an available update and installed it on two machines, but in both cases, after installing and restarting VS, it still shows up as an available update. Morever, when you try and install it, it invokes the VS installer and tries to re-install components that I already have installed.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: You are right. It's happening the same to me. Current Version: 14.0.50925.4. New Version: 14.0.51016.1. Launching the installer doesn't allow me to update anything.

Comment: Yes, god dxxn it. The same here. Please Microsoft VS team quickly see this message and fix it asap.
After installing this problematic update 4, your Cordova Project is also failed to be opened by VS anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio at Microsoft.

A mistake was made publishing this update. At the moment it will re-install update 3 rather than install update 4.

I'm terribly sorry for the inconvenience this has caused you. We are aware of the problem and are working to resolve it. I will update this answer when it's been fixed.

** Update 11/2/2015 9:44AM ** We have temporarily pulled the update notification to prevent further confusion. We will republish the notification once we've fixed the issue and verified that everything is working as expected. That should happen in a day or two. Thanks for your patience and understanding.

** Update 11/3/2015 4:45PM ** We just released update 4. You should see the notification in visual studio and the installer should work properly this time. Please let me know if you have any problems and thanks again for your patience!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to download and install update 4 manually (outside of VS)?

Comment: Unfortunately, for legal reasons we cannot distribute the download link for this update. We are working on changing that so that future updates can be downloaded directly from our download center. That should be possible starting with update 5.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior on my system. I searched the Microsoft website for similar bug reports but nobody seems to have this issue. This stackverflow message is the first one that describes the problem.

There was in the past a similar problem with other plugins or components they got never fixed. Only until next release, there was a fix. So I suspect we will have to wait.

Comment: here many users have reported this problem
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f52dfab8-dc91-4328-bbff-d49caebdbb03/update-isnt-recognized?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova