# Visual studio (2015) tools for Apache Cordova Update 4 failed to install

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to install the update 4 of Apache Cordova (VS2015). But it instantly comes back with the following error message:
The selected Visual Studio item 'Visual Studio Tools For Apache Cordova Update 4' failed to install. Check the %TEMP% directory for VS install logs.
When I go to that directory, I don't see any log related to this install. Even when sorting everything on date descending, there is no log related to this install.
This update can't be found on the Microsoft site either as a separate download or something.
Anyone else bumped into this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is anyone having problems installing VS Tools for Apache Cordova Update 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450192/is-anyone-having-problems-installing-vs-tools-for-apache-cordova-update-4)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're looking in the correct %TEMP% directory for VS install logs, since each user account on your computer will have a separate user account. **Try checking that the %TEMP% folder you're in is the right one for the user account associated with VS2015 on your local machine.** It should look something like "Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Apache_Cordova_20151106165019_001_ApacheCordovaTools.msi".

Once you're in the right folder, try looking in %TEMP% again for the log. I'd recommend sorting the folder by date added and looking for a file with the term "Cordova" in it.

Also, make sure you're connected to the internet when you install.